# Java Forms login doesn't work when RBAC enabled

Tags: java, wildfly, forms-authentication

Following the documentation on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html I got forms login working.

I tried the variations: Firstly, a form with `action="j_security_check"`. Second, using this in JSP:

```
<%
if(request.getRemoteUser() == null ){
    try{
        request.login("hussain", "mypassword");
        out.println( "Logged in" );
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.println( "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
    }   
}else{
    out.println( request.getRemoteUser() + " is already logged in");
}
%>
```

I am using WildFly 12 on Windows.

I added users using add-user.bat. The users get added to \standalone\configuration\application-users.properties. I secured a page in web.xml:

```
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>WRCollection</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>AuthConstraint</description>
            <role-name>TutorialUser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>TutorialUser</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

The /test.jsp doesn't show unless I login. So, everything is good.

Next, I enabled role based authentication using:

```
cd /core-service=management/access=authorization
:write-attribute(name=provider, value=rbac)
```

Stuck at this point. Login stops working.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use-case works on my Linux machine. You can try to enable detailed security logging and find what's the problem from the log output.

These are the JBoss CLI commands to reconfigure the logging:

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.security:add(level=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.security:add(level=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.picketbox:add(level=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.apache.catalina.authenticator:add(level=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.web.security:add(level=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.domain.management.security:add(level=ALL)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.wildfly.security:add(level=ALL)
```

BTW. The RBAC configuration is valid for the management interface, it's not related to the application security. (Or at least it should not be. If it is, then it's a bug.)

Comment: Thanks. Shall try this and see. It's not for applications? Seems I have misunderstood the whole thing then. I was wondering why the users I add using add-user.bat are not appearing in the management console.

Comment: Actually, I see I should start paying more attention; the whole syntax of the command ````cd /core-service=management/access=authorization```` makes it obvious what it is. Really feel stupid.